# What software libraries, tools or frameworks do you use for turning tabular sensor data from the field into cleaned data files

Tags: data-analysis, software, field-measurements, environmental-sensors

Cleaning data and turning it into a useable format that can be integrated with other datasets is a time-consuming task that earth scientists face when using sensor data. Most sensors output data in a highly idiosyncratic format that must typically be restructured before it can be meaningfully analyzed or imported into a database

What software, libraries, frameworks, or tools do you use to perform these tasks? I'm most interested in things that handle time-series data from sensors, but I welcome answers that provide solutions for any field data processing and cleaning tasks

I will compile answers below, starting with several that I have found:

**Libraries**

[MeteoIO](https://models.slf.ch/p/meteoio/)

**Python**

[DIT](https://github.com/PermaData/DIT)